# Como fazer o Split em algumas linhas excetuando específicas?

Tags: c#, string, regex, vb.net

Quero fazer uma lista dinâmica que usa o `Regex.Split` separando cada item pelo caractere de **uma nova linha**, exceto quando estiver nos campos **( ... )** nas minhas linhas de código, como segue o exemplo:

```
var x = 'the quick fox jumps over the lazy dog'
var n = 'myChar (string:substring, x, 3) !!!'

writeLn 'first value = $x, final = $n'

if $n = $null (
      #aqui está o erro
      #ele da split aqui
      writeLn 'error'
)
#e assim por diante...
```

Quero todas as linhas separadas por novas linhas, exemplo o que **eu quero**:

```
ind.    valor do elemento
------- -------------------------------------------------
0       var x = 'the quick fox jumps over the lazy dog'
1       var n = 'myChar (string:substring, x, 3) !!!'
2       writeLn 'first value = $x, final = $n'
3       if $n = $null (
            #aqui está o erro
            #ele da split aqui
            writeLn 'error'
        )
4       #e assim por diante...
```

Mas está retornando isso:

```
ind.    valor do elemento
------- -------------------------------------------------
0       var x = 'the quick fox jumps over the lazy dog'
1       var n = 'myChar (string:substring, x, 3) !!!'
2       writeLn 'first value = $x, final = $n'
3       if $n = $null (
4           #aqui está o erro    
5           #ele da split aqui
6           writeLn 'error'
7       )
        #e assim por diante...
```

Abaixo tem uma imagem para melhor descrever o que é detectado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a Regex que estou usando: **`(?!.*('|\(|\)))\n`**

> Aceito respostas em Regex, ou VB.NET / C# (preferência VB)

Comment: Uma dica seria remover os comentários que não serve para a execução.

Replace (\#.*)(\n*) por "", depois você passa o seu regex. O que acha?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi olhando seu exemplo do que é o certo, você está querendo fazer um *parser*. É algo bem mais complexo do que você imagina e acho pouco provável que alguém vai lhe entregar algum só com esta recompensa. E se entendi seu objetivo final, o *parser* é melhor mesmo porque você terá uma série de problemas deste tipo. A descrição do problema não bate muito com o exemplo.

Comment: tem como postar parte do código para entendermos melhor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu sei que não é o que você quer mas a melhor resposta que eu posso lhe dar é não usar `RegEx` para isto. Até porque não é só isto que você vai querer fazer com esta *string*. Seu exemplo já mostra porque. Eu até pensei em fazer uma padrão que lhe atendesse mas ele seria furado, pura perda de tempo.

Eu aprecio a sua vontade de fazer isto, é melhor do que a maioria dos programadores que só seguem receita de bolo e nem entendem como as coisas funcionam. Você está querendo fazer uma linguagem de programação. Mas precisa fazer do jeito certo.

Sem um [*parser*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) você não vai conseguir nenhum resultado nem minimamente satisfatório. Há ambiguidades no código. No seu exemplo se eu verificar os parênteses, vai pegar qualquer coisa, inclusive parênteses existentes dentro de *strings*, como é o caso visto no seu exemplo de texto ou ainda dentro de comentários ou ainda vai considerar parênteses em expressões ou outro contexto onde eles podem ser usados. Sem ter um entendimento do que cada [*token*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token) do código é, não dá para selecionar nada de forma correta e executar ações específicas. O entendimento correto do contexto onde o *token* se encontra só pode ser obtido como um mecanismo mais sofisticado de *parser*.

Recomendo fortemente começar a ler sobre o assunto de *parsing* ou de criação de linguagens de programação. Embora tecnicamente seja possível criar um conjunto de padrões para realizar a tarefa, ficará tão complexo, ineficiente e provavelmente problemático que é melhor simplesmente esquecer `RegEx`.

Não coloco código porque depende de uma série de fatores e é algo muito grande para ser uma resposta.

- [Nossa tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parser)
- [Construção de compiladores](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/)
- [A bíblia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers%3A_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) para quando quiser fazer algo realmente sofisticado.
- [Artigo sobre .NET para criar linguagens](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272494/Implementing-Programming-Languages-using-Csharp) que pode interessar.